# How to access files in FileSystemStorage in Browser component

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to display a pdf saved in FileSystemStorage inside the browsercomponent, but it keeping giving me this error on the console: `[0813/072549.347989:INFO:CONSOLE(37)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file://home//Chapter_11.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitH", source: https://cn1app/streams/1 (37) [0813/072551.123557:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file://home//Chapter_11.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitH", source: https://cn1app/streams/1 (0)` . Its like there is a restriction that I need to work around. How can I go around this?

Edits... Added information below.

This is the code I am using:

```
Form hi;
Container loadingMsg;

public void Home(){
    Form form = new Form("Display pdf", new BorderLayout());
    
    Button showPdf = new Button("Show Pdf");
    showPdf.addActionListener(l->{
        show();
    });
    
    form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, showPdf);
    form.show();
}

private void show(){
 
    hi = new Form("PDF Viewer", new BorderLayout());
    Label loadingLabel = new Label("Loading PDF...");
    loadingMsg = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(loadingLabel);
    hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, loadingMsg);
    
    String pdfUrl = "https://as.vanderbilt.edu/chemistry/Rizzo/chem220a/Chapter_11.pdf";
    String fileName = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "Chapter_11";
    
    if (!FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(fileName)) {
        Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground(pdfUrl, fileName);
    };
   
    hi.addShowListener(l -> {
        run1(fileName);
    });
    hi.show();
}

private void run1(String fileName) {
    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setPage(getPdfViewerHtml(fileName), null);
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
    loadingMsg.remove();
    hi.revalidate();

}

private String getPdfViewerHtml(String fileName) {
      String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
            + "<html>\n"
            + "  <head>\n"
            + "    <title>PDF Viewer</title>\n"
            + "    <style>\n"
            + "    html{\n"
            + "      height: 100%;\n"
            + "      padding: 0;\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "    body{\n"
            + "      height: 100%;\n"
            + "      overflow-y: hidden;\n"
            + "      position: fixed;\n"
            + "      width: 100%;\n"
            + "      padding: 0;\n"
            + " margin: 0;\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "    </style>\n"
            + "  </head>\n"
            + "  <body>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "    <div style= \"height: 100%; margin: 0;\">\n"
            + "        <iframe\n"
            + "          src='"+fileName+"#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitH'\n"
            + "          width=\"100%\"\n"
            + "          height=\"100%\"\n"
            + "        >\n"
            + "        <p>This browser does not support PDF!</p>\n"
            + "        </iframe>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "    </div>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "  </body>\n"
            + "</html>";
    return html;
}
```

So in the method `String getPdfViewerHtml(String fileName)`,when i replace the `fileName` with a URL, thing works fine. But I want it to display a file from FileSystemStorage.

Comment: How are you trying to load it? This might be due to same origin restrictions in the browser.
This is on the simulator right? Please specify if you're using CEF or FX in that case https://www.codenameone.com/blog/big-changes-jcef.html

Comment: I am using CEF.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Do you mean that is it possible to access files in the FileSystemStorage inside a BrowserComponent without using the cn1lib https://github.com/shannah/CN1Webserver? Moreover, how can we debug the errors that happen inside a BrowserComponent? For example, if it is really a CORS problem as you imagined, or another kind of problem, how can we see the internal browser console? Do we have to look at the native logs or are they errors that can be intercepted and logged through CN1?

Comment: @RichardMatovu you didn't answer the other questions in my comment?

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani you can load an HTML hierarchy entirely from filesystem. We support placing HTML code in the html root package and you can use that as a filesystem web UI. A webserver is only needed for things that won't work well in a filesystem browser which is an edge case

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Ok, but we are discussing of a pdf file that is downloaded at runtime to the FileSystemStorage, not of a pdf that is placed in the html root package at compile time. Maybe the question wasn’t enought clear, but I previously discussed the code with RichardMatovu

Comment: Sorry @ShaiAlmog.. I have added the code. The whole process is, when a user selects a pdf to view, it checks the FileSystemStorage if it exists there, and if it doesn't, then it goes to my online server and it downloads the file to FileSystemStorage. So to view it, I display it in a browsercomponent using the Chrome Embedded Pdf viewer. So the issue is, if the link (fileName in the code) is an online link, it works perfectly but totally fails when it is a link to FileSystemStorage.

Comment: The whole point of picking it from FileSystemStorage is, my app has an offline mode. So a file is downloaded once and saved in the FileSystemStorage and it should be viewed whether a user is  online or offline .

Comment: @RichardMatovu About the code that you have just posted, I noted that `Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground` can complete the upload AFTER the `run1(String fileName)` is executed, so it can throws an exception because the file isn't available yet. When the download is in background (like in this case), it's executed in a parallel thread of the NetworkManager.

Comment: The HTML package works by unzipping the content to file system storage and browsing there so it "should" work. There are caveats. E.g. what's "filename"?
Make sure it's a relative path that points at the same directory hierarchy e.g. "mypdf.pdf". And make sure that both the PDF and HTML are written to the same directory. `file:/` URLs won't work for the browser component as they're specific to our code.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog On which directory of the FileSystemStorage is the content of the HTML package unzipped?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog the fileName is the location I pass on calling that method. I specified it there: String fileName = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "Chapter_11";

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani even when the file is already in the FileSystemStorage it doesnot work. Thus is in regard to the comment where I used `Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground`. But that can be adjusted

Comment: The whole issue is, the error reads that, "Not allowed to load local resource" which I would thing that it is possibly seeing it but it cannot load it.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I fixed the code of Richard, but it works only in the Simulator, please see my answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should support the local embed tag correctly:

```java
    private Container loadingMsg;

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        home();
    }


    public void home() {
        Form form = new Form("Display pdf", new BorderLayout());

        Button showPdf = new Button("Show Pdf");
        showPdf.addActionListener(l -> {
            showPdf.setText("Dowloading PDF...");
            showPdf.setEnabled(false);
            form.revalidate();
            show();
        });

        form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, showPdf);
        form.show();
    }

    private void show() {
        String root = getAppHomePath() + "httpdocs/";
        mkdir(root);
        
        hi = new Form("PDF Viewer", new BorderLayout());
        Label loadingLabel = new Label("Loading PDF...");
        loadingMsg = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(loadingLabel);
        hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, loadingMsg);

        String pdfUrl = "https://as.vanderbilt.edu/chemistry/Rizzo/chem220a/Chapter_11.pdf";
        String fileName = root + "/Chapter_11.pdf";

        if (!FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(fileName)) {
            Util.downloadUrlToFile(pdfUrl, fileName, false);
            try {
                run1(docRoot, "Chapter_11.pdf");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(ex);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                run1(docRoot, fileName);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(ex);
            }
        }

        hi.show();
    }

    private void run1(String docRoot, String fileName) throws IOException {
        
        BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
        String localUrl = fileName;
        String htmlPage = getPdfViewerHtml(localUrl);
        File indexHtml = new File(docRoot, "index.html");
        writeStringToFile(indexHtml, htmlPage);
        browser.setURL(docRoot + "/index.html");
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
        loadingMsg.remove();
        hi.revalidate();

    }

    private String getPdfViewerHtml(String fileName) {
        String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "  <head>\n"
                + "    <title>PDF Viewer</title>\n"
                + "    <style>\n"
                + "    html{\n"
                + "      height: 100%;\n"
                + "      padding: 0;\n"
                + "    }\n"
                + "    body{\n"
                + "      height: 100%;\n"
                + "      overflow-y: hidden;\n"
                + "      position: fixed;\n"
                + "      width: 100%;\n"
                + "      padding: 0;\n"
                + " margin: 0;\n"
                + "    }\n"
                + "    </style>\n"
                + "  </head>\n"
                + "  <body>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "    <div style= \"height: 100%; margin: 0;\">\n"
                + "        <iframe\n"
                + "          src='" + fileName + "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitH'\n"
                + "          width=\"100%\"\n"
                + "          height=\"100%\"\n"
                + "        >\n"
                + "        <p>This browser does not support PDF!</p>\n"
                + "        </iframe>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "    </div>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "  </body>\n"
                + "</html>";
        return html;
    }
    
    private void writeStringToFile(File file, String content) throws IOException {
        FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        try (OutputStream os = fs.openOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            Util.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes("UTF-8")), os);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Edited your answer with a more specific file name and removed some boilerplate

Comment: That works well. It displays the file from the system storage; it works perfectly on simulator but on phone (tested on Android), it does not display. It just displays a white screen.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog on this part `String root = getAppHomePath() + "httpdocs/";
        mkdir(root);` if the root exists, won't it be replaced and all its contents lost?

Comment: No. It will just try to create the directory. If it exists it won't do anything